# Automatically lombokifying a project

Tags: java, coding-style, lombok

I have a largish Java project that we're introducing [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org) into.  For at least some of the superficial integrations I'd like to do a one-time automatic pass through the whole codebase and update all the files to use Lombok.

Specifically, I'd like to replace all the log declarations with `@Log4J` and all `getFoo`/`setFoo` methods where they are only getting or setting a private field `foo` to use `@Getter`/`@Setter`. So far I haven't found any preexisting scripts that seem to do this.

Has anyone already done something similar?  Any suggestions on good ways to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

A simple text-replacment solution could leverage awk to process all of the source files, with matchers for the lines requiring substitution / deletion / addition, etc. Awk should provide the needed flexibility to handle the specific coding style for each such project or module. Since coding styles differ widely across organizations, finding a pre-existing solution would seem to be unlikely.

Comment: I'd be satisfied with an awk solution that works for any reasonable coding standard, even if it's not universal. I am not proficient enough with awk that I think I could write a reliable solution for this. I was initially thinking of a solution that worked from the AST representation, but as long as the results are accurate I don't really care about the implementation.